# Using Spring @RequestBody to convert JSON with mixed convention in payload to Entity Object

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I am using Spring `@RequestBody` to map a JSON payload to a Java Object. Unfortunately this JSON payload does not use a set convention but rather has names that use both camelCase and snake_case.

To be clear my `Controller` looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mobile/device", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<Object> flagDevice (@RequestBody List<MobileDeviceData> deviceInfoList) {
    ... code here ...
}
```

with the `MobileDeviceData` `Entity` object having several setter methods like:

```
public void setDeviceName(String deviceName) {
    this.deviceName = deviceName;
}

public void setFlagId(int flagId) {
    this.flagId = flagId;
}
```

This works great and without any extra effort when the JSON objects name is camelCase. However for snake_case names I need to add the `Annotation`:

```
@JsonProperty("flag_id")
private int flagId;
```

in order for it to be picked up.

I know it's not a good idea to use the `@JsonProperty` if it can be avoided as you then will need to annotate every parameter. My question is, is there a more general way to enforce matching snake_case with the corresponding camelCase in the `Entity` object? And obviously to do it without screwing up the ones that are already camelCase.

Comment: So your JSON contains both camel case and snake case names?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes.

Comment: That's a shame. Jackson has a concept of naming strategy but I doubt it has an implementation that considers both. I think your best bet is to write and register a JSON deserializer for your type that knows exactly what names to expect.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis At that point I'm probably better off just using JsonProperty annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having been working on this a bit, I now realize doing anything like what was requested would be counterproductive.

When you receive (deserialize) a JSON Object, it is generally expected that you will deliver (serialize) with the same parameters. If an implementation extracted both camelCase and underscore parameters the same way, then it would not know how to deserialize correctly later on. By following a standard convention and then using `@JsonProperty` for all the exceptions, it remains possible to deserialize and later deliver the JSON object just as it was received.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [article here](https://www.sghill.net/how-do-i-write-a-jackson-json-serializer-deserializer.html), there is a simple approach to deserialize the `MobileDeviceData` class. Here is the sample code as below:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = UserDeserializer.class)
public class User {
    private ObjectId id;
    private String   username;
    private String   password;
    public User(ObjectId id, String username, String password) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public ObjectId getId()       { return id; }
    public String   getUsername() { return username; }
    public String   getPassword() { return password; }
}
```

Assume User is the class we’re interested in writing the Deserializer for. Not much is notable here, except for the annotations that tell Jackson who knows how `deserialize` this class.

```
public class UserDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer {
    @Override
    public User deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser,
            DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jsonParser);
        return new User(null,
                node.get("username").getTextValue(),
                node.get("password").getTextValue());
    }
}
```

The deserializer is created by extending Jackson’s abstract `JsonDeserializer` class, and giving it the type we want to `deserialize` to. Difficult is figuring out that you can reference the JSON by `field name` with the `JsonParser`'s `ObjectCodec`.

I hope it helps.
Please feel free to comment if needed!

Comment: This seems a lot more complicated than just using the JsonProperty annotation!?

Comment: Thats right, cause you are writing the deserialization logic here.

Comment: Why write a bunch of deserialization code when that is already written for you? Now instead of just of just annotating the correct property name, I have to write my own JsonDeserializer logic, I still have to notate what the correct property name is and inject the values. Not only is this a lot more code, but I now have a complex Deserialization class I have to maintain.

Comment: You don't want to use the `@JsonProperty` annotations and you want `@RequestBody` to also work. Keeping both of the things in mind, this is the best solution that I could propose. There are many other ways, that will not work with `@RequestBody`.  And in all of these solutions, you have to write your own code to perform the customized work, there is no way to get away from that!